# Multi covariate time series forecast using Darts

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, multivariate-time-series, u8darts

I am trying to use the tutorial [here](https://unit8.com/resources/time-series-forecasting-using-past-and-future-external-data-with-darts/), where we have two covariates to predict the target.

The tutorial uses `.stack()` to add two covariates together. It is not clear to me how to use this function to add more than two covariates to the model.

I tried the following code:

```
from darts.models import BlockRNNModel


my_covariate = (tg.sine_timeseries(length=LENGTH, 
                                value_frequency=(1/14), 
                                freq='D', 
                                column_name='my_covariate')
             + 0.4 * tg.gaussian_timeseries(length=LENGTH, freq='D'))


brnn_melting_and_rain = BlockRNNModel(input_chunk_length=30, 
                                      output_chunk_length=10, 
                                      n_rnn_layers=2)

brnn_melting_and_rain.fit(flow_train, 
                          # past_covariates=melting.stack(rainfalls).stack(rainfalls), 
                          past_covariates=[melting,rainfalls,my_covariate],
                          epochs=10, 
                          verbose=True)

eval_model(brnn_melting_and_rain, 
           past_covariates=melting.stack(rainfalls))
```

But I got the following error:

> ValueError: The provided sequence of target series must have the same
> length as the provided sequence of covariate series.

I tried reading the documentation of DARTS, but there is no clear direction on how to use past_covariates, in specific, what is the data type I should pass here and if there are any other requirements.

Comment: In case someone is wondering, the `tg` comes from `from darts.utils import timeseries_generation as tg`.

Comment: What's `flow_train`?

Answer (score 4):

Use **[API's `concatenate` to stack many time series properly](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/userguide/timeseries.html#creating-timeseries)**, rather than passing a list or invoking many `stack` calls (e.g. avoid "stacking stack").

For instance, build the multivariate data along with your custom features this way

```py
from darts import concatenate
past_covariates = concatenate([melting, rainfalls, my_covariate], axis=1)
past_covariates
inspect visually
```

[image]
and then **train on this multivariate time series**

```py
brnn_melting.fit(flow_train, 
                 past_covariates=past_covariates, 
                 epochs=100, 
                 verbose=True)
```

Note: although not recommended, "stacking stack" is essentially equivalent to concatenation

```py
from darts import concatenate

past_covariates = concatenate([melting, rainfalls, my_covariate], axis=1)
past_covariates_old = melting.stack(rainfalls).stack(my_covariate)
assert past_covariates == past_covariates_old
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasting from your code and from the link you provide I've managed to get a working code (no error) but I'm not sure that's what you want.

```
from darts.models import BlockRNNModel
from darts.utils import timeseries_generation as tg
from darts.metrics import rmse


def eval_model(model, past_covariates=None, future_covariates=None):
    # Past and future covariates are optional because they won't always be used in our tests
    
    # We backtest the model on the last 20% of the flow series, with a horizon of 10 steps:
    backtest = model.historical_forecasts(series=flow, 
                                          past_covariates=past_covariates,
                                          future_covariates=future_covariates,
                                          start=0.8, 
                                          retrain=False,
                                          verbose=True, 
                                          forecast_horizon=10)
    
    flow[-len(backtest)-100:].plot()
    backtest.plot(label='backtest (n=10)')
    print('Backtest RMSE = {}'.format(rmse(flow, backtest)))


LENGTH = 3 * 365

my_covariate = (tg.sine_timeseries(length=LENGTH, 
                                   value_frequency=(1/14), 
                                   freq='D', 
                                   column_name='my_covariate')
             + 0.4 * tg.gaussian_timeseries(length=LENGTH, freq='D'))

melting = (tg.sine_timeseries(length=LENGTH, 
                              value_frequency=(1/365), 
                              freq='D', 
                              column_name='melting')
           + 0.15 * tg.gaussian_timeseries(length=LENGTH, freq='D'))

rainfalls = (tg.sine_timeseries(length=LENGTH, 
                                value_frequency=(1/14), 
                                freq='D', 
                                column_name='rainfall')
             + 0.3 * tg.gaussian_timeseries(length=LENGTH, freq='D'))

melting_contribution = 0.5 * melting.shift(5)

all_contributions = [melting_contribution] + [0.1 * rainfalls.shift(lag) for lag in range(5)]

flow = sum(
    [series[melting_contribution.start_time():][:melting.end_time()] 
     for series in all_contributions]
).with_columns_renamed('melting', 'flow')

brnn_melting_and_rain = BlockRNNModel(input_chunk_length=30, 
                                      output_chunk_length=10, 
                                      n_rnn_layers=2)
brnn_melting_and_rain.fit(flow, 
                          # past_covariates=melting.stack(rainfalls).stack(rainfalls), 
                          # past_covariates=[melting,rainfalls,my_covariate],
                          past_covariates=melting.stack(rainfalls).stack(my_covariate),
                          epochs=10, 
                          verbose=True)

flow_train, _ = flow.split_before(0.8)

eval_model(brnn_melting_and_rain, 
           #past_covariates=melting.stack(rainfalls)
           past_covariates=melting.stack(rainfalls).stack(my_covariate)
          )
```

The main thing was to stack the time series with `melting.stack(rainfalls).stack(my_covariate)` and then passing it also to the `eval_model` method.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue and allow you to fit the model using the covariate time series.

```
from darts.models import BlockRNNModel

my_covariate = (tg.sine_timeseries(length=LENGTH, 
                                value_frequency=(1/14), 
                                freq='D', 
                                column_name='my_covariate')
             + 0.4 * tg.gaussian_timeseries(length=LENGTH, freq='D'))

# Trim all the time series so they are the same length
flow_train = flow_train.trim()
melting = melting.trim()
rainfalls = rainfalls.trim()
my_covariate = my_covariate.trim()

brnn_melting_and_rain = BlockRNNModel(input_chunk_length=30, 
                                      output_chunk_length=10, 
                                      n_rnn_layers=2)

brnn_melting_and_rain.fit(flow_train, 
                          past_covariates=[melting,rainfalls,my_covariate],
                          epochs=10, 
                          verbose=True)

eval_model(brnn_melting_and_rain, 
           past_covariates=melting.stack(rainfalls))
```